# Python: input file is output file

Tags: python, file-io, command-line

I want to write some kind of file parser using python.
It shall read a file line-by-line, to some replacement if necessary, and then write the "new" line to an output file.
It shall be invoked from the command line (to be part of my C build process).

What I already have is fine, and can be used like

```
python convert.py -i input.txt -o output.txt
```

However, as this parser is not intended to create new files but to modifiy existing files, this solution is disappointing.
I want to change my script to work like

```
python convert.py textfile.txt
```

What I know is that I cannot open a file for reading and writing, because the open(myFile "w") will erase the file.
So, what is the best way to proceed?

- Parse the whole file, close it, do the conversion, open file for writing? This will require all the data to be stored in memory. A file can have up to 15.000 lines
- Write to a temp file, delete the input file after processing, rename the temp file? This feels somehow... strange.
- Write the output to stdout instead of an output file? Then one can use stream operators like > or | from command line.

However, i tried this:

```
python convert.py textfile.txt > textfile.txt
```

and the result was an empty file. The following is working:

```
python convert.py textfile.txt > textfile2.txt
```

So, I think the > operator is not working as intended if the file is opened by my script.
But, I would be more happy if command-line stream operators could be avoided.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `What I know is that I cannot open a file for reading and writing, because the open(myFile "w") will erase the file.` Open as `r+`?

Answer (score 3):

You could open two files, read the original, do something with the data, and write it into a new file. At the end move the new file to the old. This way you can read line by line and dont need to have all in memory.

```
import shutil
with open('original.txt') as old, open('newtest.txt', 'w') as new:
    for line in old:
        new.write(line)

shutil.move('newtest.txt', 'original.txt')
```

Comment: This is basically the same approach as from metatoaster. Im fine with that.

Answer (score 1):

I will work backwards from your question.

```
python convert.py textfile.txt > textfile.txt
```

The `>` shell operator opens the target file for writing immediately, which in turn immediately truncates that file which then uh, 0 bytes input.

> - Write to a temp file, delete the input file after processing, rename the temp file? This feels somehow... strange.

That's actually how `sed` (a command-line utility) does it.  Read the `info` entry for `sed`, find `-i`:

```
`-i[SUFFIX]'
`--in-place[=SUFFIX]'
     This option specifies that files are to be edited in-place.  GNU
     `sed' does this by creating a temporary file and sending output to
     this file rather than to the standard output.(1).

     This option implies `-s'.

     When the end of the file is reached, the temporary file is renamed
     to the output file's original name.  The extension, if supplied,
     is used to modify the name of the old file before renaming the
     temporary file, thereby making a backup copy(2)).
```

So when a highly used utility does it that way, you can be pretty sure that is probably the sane way to do what you want to do.

Anyway, just use the solution that @nouseforname provided.

---

If you think about it though, your file is basically a stream of sequential bytes on disk.  If your changes involve removing then adding different amounts of bytes, how can you do that?  The answer is you have to rewrite some bytes at the beginning at the next segment to the new location, and once you get to that point why not just stash it at a different location?  Like a different file?

... of course, someone could implement a filesystem that transparently handle this, but generally this isn't done.

That said, there is a *possible* way if your changes are not going to change the total length of the file.  You can use the [`mmap`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html) module for this, and I am going to shameless steal their example

```
import mmap

# write a simple example file
with open("hello.txt", "wb") as f:
    f.write("Hello Python!\n")

with open("hello.txt", "r+b") as f:
    # memory-map the file, size 0 means whole file
    mm = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0)
    # read content via standard file methods
    print mm.readline()  # prints "Hello Python!"
    # read content via slice notation
    print mm[:5]  # prints "Hello"
    # update content using slice notation;
    # note that new content must have same size
    mm[6:] = " world!\n"
    # ... and read again using standard file methods
    mm.seek(0)
    print mm.readline()  # prints "Hello  world!"
    # close the map
    mm.close()
```

So there is a way, but generally this "same size" assumption is not true when replacing text in a file.

Comment: Well, I always wondered how the GNU tools do it. If they are doing it this way, then it should work for me, too.

Comment: @lugge86 Not sure if the `mmap` suggestion will help, because replacements text typically are not of the same length as original.